# default size of Event-Server messages between nodejs and browser

Tags: node.js, server-sent-events

I use Event-Server/EventSource mechanism between nodejs "http" server and Chrome browser.

I have switched from WebSocket to Event-Server mechanism, because I exchange a lot of data (Distance & Angle detections from a Lidar, so 360 set of data {angle, distance}, 10 times each second in JSON/string format, between acquisition application and display on the Browser.

I had no problem to send data with Websocket, but it seem that Event-Server mechanism lost big messages like above.
When I answer to Event-Server request, I doesn't set specific information in http-header, except:

```
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
```

- Is there a default maximum size of message in http answer ?
- How to increase this limit ?
- or do I need to 'write' data block-by-block ?

  let jsn = [ { angle: 0, distance: 250}, { angle: 2, distance: 253}, { angle: 3, distance: 255},...];

  this.response.write( `data: ${JSON.stringify(jsn)}\n\n`);

Best regards.

Comment: How big in bytes is your "big message". And are they all lost, or just some of them? Are you using http/1 or http/2? If you can show reproducible code, server and/or client, it'd help.

Comment: Not what your asked, but websockets and event source should use basically the same bandwidth for the same data.  Of course, if you only push data 1-way, websockets is overkill, so event source is sensible.

Comment: Each message is around 10 Kb, and sent 10 times by second.

Comment: In that case the problem won't be data size. Obviously seeing the server-side code would help, but my guesses would be you either are not flushing the data out, or are not keeping the connection open. The chrome console log, network tab, will give you more information about what is going on. (If there is a gateway server, or similar, between server and client, that could also be getting in the way, I suppose.)